# C++ Recursion function

Tags: c++

Good afternoon everyone, I am new to recursion and am trying to create a program to take user input to build a math function. It works when doing simple things such as 3 + 4, but when trying something like (3 + 4) + 6 the main prints an empty string. The purpose of the program is to place nested numbers inside parenthesis to make them clear to read. I have tried following the code, but the recursion seems to be what i don't understand. Thanks for your time and help.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string buildEq(bool nested, string tab);

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the equation builder!" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Each step can only have one operation between two numbers." << endl;
    cout << "So the equation (3 + 4) + 6 would have one 'nested' operation." << endl << endl;

    string equation = buildEq(false, "");

    cout << endl << "The equation you have built is... " << equation << endl;
    cout << endl << "Thanks for coming!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

string buildEq(bool nested, string tab)
{
    string equation;

    string nesting;
    cout << tab << "For this step, is there nesting? (y/n): ";
    cin >> nesting;

    if(nesting == "y")
    {
        nested = true;
        tab += "\t";
        buildEq(true, tab);
    }

    else
    {
        int number = 0;
        int operation_count = 1;
        while(number < 2)
        {
            if(nested == true)
            {
                equation += "(";
            }

            string num= "";
            cout << tab << "What number would you like to enter: ";
            cin >> num;
            equation += num+= " ";

            number++;

            while(operation_count == 1)
            {
            string operation;
            cout << tab << "What operation would you like to perform? (+, -, /, *): ";
            cin >> operation;
            equation += operation += " ";
            operation_count++;
            }

            if(nested == true && number == 2)
            {
                equation += ")";
            }

        }
    }

    return equation;
}
```

Correct output

```
Welcome to the equation builder!

Each step can only have one operation between two numbers.
So the equation (3 + 4) + 6 would have one 'nested' operation.

For this step, is there nesting? (y/n): n
What number would you like to enter: 3
What operation would you like to perform? (+, -, /, *): +
What number would you like to enter: 4

The equation you have built is... 3 + 4

Thanks for coming!
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Function results empty

```
Welcome to the equation builder!

Each step can only have one operation between two numbers.
So the equation (3 + 4) + 6 would have one 'nested' operation.

For this step, is there nesting? (y/n): y
        For this step, is there nesting? (y/n): n
        What number would you like to enter: 3
        What operation would you like to perform? (+, -, /, *): +
        What number would you like to enter: 4

The equation you have built is...

Thanks for coming!
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: Recursive functions generally call themselves and do something with that output. When you call `buildEq` in `buildEq` you don't do anything with the output.

Comment: Think of the base case you need and go from there

Comment: ***Rule of thumb:** Look at earlier errors before addressing later ones.* (Note: maybe not address the earlier errors, but do look at them.) Once your program goes off-track, it might be useless to look at how badly it careens into the void. In this case, the first erroroneous behavior I see is not the empty equation; it's the lack of opportunity to enter "+6" in the nested case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Probably an overkill, but I don't think that the question itself is an easy example for understanding recursions)

In order to understand the recursion part, we need to look at the general problem, and understand how we progress from one invocation to another (the *recursive step*), and what is our stopping point (the *base case*) . Your goal here is to create a ***valid*** equation, in order to do so, your input should follow certain guidelines. Specifically, in order to verify such a problem, you need to verify that each input is following a syntax which is called ***Context Free Grammar***, denoted by the following rules (N stands for number or nested, O for operation, D for digit and $ for nothing):

```
N ->  ( N ) O | D O
D ->   0-9
O ->  + N | - N | * N | / N | $
```

There are *two* recursions here. In each stage we need to get a valid equation, and those rules make sure it stays like that.

The following code is creating a **proper** equation from the user.

Notice a few important notes -

1. I'm using std::stringstream, which is more efficient at creating strings and appending to the existing "string".
2. You should not over-use std::endl, since in addition to adding a line break, it also flushes to the stdout, which is expensive.
3. Using "Using namespace std;" isn't a good habit!
4. Look at how I pass the same stringstream, and each stage adds to this, in order to create the general string. If your code doesn't add to the "carried" value, it means that you are doing nothing in this recursive step.

The code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

#include <assert.h>

void get_num_or_nested(std::stringstream& eq);
void get_operation_or_stop(std::stringstream& eq);

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    int digit_count = 0;

    for (const char& character : s)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(character))
        {
            ++digit_count;
        }
    }

    return !s.empty() && s.size() == digit_count;
}

bool is_operation(char c)
{
    return (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/');
}

std::string get_input_from_user()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;    
}

void get_operation_or_stop(std::stringstream& eq)
{
    std::cout << "Insert one of the following:\n";
    std::cout << "An operation - [ + | - | * | / ]\n";
    std::cout << "s for Stop" << std::endl;

    std::string input = get_input_from_user();

    if (input.size() == 1)
    {
        if (is_operation(input[0]))
        {
            eq << input;
            get_num_or_nested(eq);
        }
        else if (input != "s")
        {
            assert(false);
        }
        // stops!
    }
    else
    {
        assert(false);
    }
}

void get_num_or_nested(std::stringstream& eq)
{
    std::cout << "Insert one of the following:\n";
    std::cout << "A number\n";
    std::cout << "n for Nested" << std::endl;

    std::string input = get_input_from_user();

    if (input == "n")
    {
        eq << "(";
        get_num_or_nested(eq);
        eq << ")";
        get_operation_or_stop(eq);
    }
    else if (is_number(input))
    {
        eq << input;
        get_operation_or_stop(eq);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(false);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to the equation builder!\n" << std::endl;

    std::stringstream eq;

    get_num_or_nested(eq);

    std::cout << "The equation you have built is... " << eq.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Thanks for coming!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Just note that all those `assert()`s will be no-ops in a release build.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is wrong is when the user says yes to nesting. Instead of calling the function and discarding what it returned, you need to return what the function returned.

```
if(nesting == "y")
{
    nested = true;
    tab += "\t";
    return buildEq(true, tab);
}
```